# Javascript: protect global variables

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am coming from C++ background, where if you have declared a namespace or class, its identifier cannot be overwritten, but in JS I just easily can create a global variable with the name of the most important namespace in the project, and ruin the entire project!

How do you, js developers, deal with it? Is there a possibility to fix global variables? If not, then how do you manage to work with big projects in JS?

Comment: Wrap code in [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), `(function() { // Code Here }());`. Also by using [Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

Comment: Any linter will complain when you try to set a global variable. Always use `var` or `let` (in ES6).

Comment: In JS almost anything can be modified or monkey-patched and you really cannot have bullet-proof protection against it. The encapsulation and other constraints in JS are usually set as a set of conventions or linters-check, not as language constructs (since there are no one)

Comment: It's not that big a deal, just don't do it. Linters like jshint and `'use strict'` help prevent accidental global variables. Also, CommonJS build systems can wrap all the code up in a reasonably contained way, excluding calls to the JavaScript environment.

Comment: You hit on the drawback of JS flexibility. Above comments are mainly true, especially the book linked on Design Pattern (see namespacing patterns section). When libraries are wrapped in [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd), then it becomes easy to assign each module to a "private" variable so that it can be used by another module / your main code, but is still "invisible" to other libraries. Other workaround is to store the previous value of the target namespace, so that in case of conflict, the application developer can still access it (in something like "namespace.noConflict")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mate, in js, you are sure to create a name space like this:

```
var mySpace ={

 propertyA: null,
 propertyB: 'ValueB',
 MethodA: function()
{
 console.log('Iam A method');
}
}
```

then, you can can call the method like

```
 mySpace.MethodA();
```

it's good in practice to create one js file per js namespace, it's easy to manage.

Comment: And then you write somewhere "mySpace = 234" occasionally, and all your good practice is gone.

Comment: @shal, I don't think mySpace =234 it's something you can occasionally write if you really thinking about using namespace..., in js, when you use variable inside a space, you need specify the namespace like mySpace.v1 = 234, if you are using local variable then it's not gonna change the global variable, you can do more researching about js name space and variable scopes ,I would never go mySpace =234 in a global level, it does not making sense to me

Comment: @shal, further more, if you are thinking name space, classes, you should not use too many glabal  variable at all, you should always wrap your function/properties inside a js namespace or class, from my personal experience, i never have a  function, property outside a namespace/class, it just mess up things once you have more complex things together

Comment: @shal, if you want, another solution will be -- trying to use something like CoffeeScript, TypeScript, they both are object oriented/c like language, which you can use very much like c/c++, they will be convert to native javascript after compilation. you can do easily use it without knowing too much around javascript. but then you lose the flexibility which js gives you ...

Comment: I think your advice on making the minimal number of things on global scope is really the thing I was looking for. It will be easier to manage a 2-2 of well known to every developer global namespaces and put everything inside those well defined namespaces and to freeze their contents by [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze). I believe that will do.

Comment: @shal, would you like to tick my answer? lol , anyway, happy coding bro!